# Offset and limit for a set

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I have two ordered sets of `Integer`s - `SortedSet<Integer>`, call them `set1` and `set2`. I need to find a union of that sets and return the subset offset 10 limit 10. What do I mean?

```
Set1:
1,2,5,6,7,8,11,21,23,543,1002

Set2:
11,12,15,16,17,8,111,121,123,1543,11002

Union:
1,2,5,6,7,8,11,21,23,543,1002,12,15,16,17,111,121,123,1543,11002

Union offset 10 limit 10:
1002,12,15,16,17,111,121,123,1543,11002
```

Note, that cardinalities of `8` and `11` in the union is `1`.

I'm looking for an algorithm that allows me to not load the entire sets into the memory (because those sets may be quite large, I would not to waste the server's resources). Is there a way to do that? Maybe some instant libraries like `commons` or `guava` can be help of?

UPD: I myself don't use Java 8, but a solution using it is also interesting.

Comment: You can't remove duplicates from set2 without loading set1 in memory (or refetch all of set1 for each number in set2, which is probably very inefficient performance wise)...

Comment: @assylias - Removing duplicates is not the goal, it's the implementation. See my answer for a "lazy" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is quite simple.

```
Create empty hash
Create empty array
Set waste counter to 0
Iterate all sets (2 or more)
  Iterate set values
    If value not in hash
      Insert value into hash
      Increase waste counter
        If waste counter > offset (10)
          Insert value into array
          If array length == limit (10)
            Done - return array
```

Comment: Thank you, it would be more helpful if you re-wrote it in Java, not in pseudo-code.

Comment: BTW, how much this algorithm more efficient than full serach?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use java (like yourself :-), but you asked for an algorithm, not implementation

Comment: That's not a problem It was just an advice).

Comment: Regarding efficiency, it's not wasteful in terms of memory (Only some of the hashed values are "wasteful"), and it's optimized in terms of iterations - You only access what you must.

Comment: As far as I could count, the complexity of full serach would be O(l_1 + l_2), where l_1 and l_2 are cardinality of the sets correspondingly. Could you help with counting the complexity for your algoriuthm>

Comment: If values inside each set are unique, I'd say it's O(offset + limit)

Comment: That's about your algorithm? Is the lenght what I called limit?

Comment: It's not quite cleare what do you mean empty hash? A hashTable?

Comment: In java, I guess a `java.util.HashSet`. In other languages, it could be `{}` (JS), `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet` (.net) and so on.. It's purpose is to efficiently identift duplicates. You could use another array from the start and iterate that everytime, but that's pointless.

Answer (score 0):

@Amit's answer is good but could still be a little memory inefficient if the offset is huge too. Here is another approach,

```
Have a pointer on each set,
while offset > 0:
    if setA pointer value < setB pointer value
        increment setA pointer
        decrement offset
    else
        increment setB pointer

add "limit" numbers starting from setA pointer to the output array.
if end of setA is reached before "limit" numbers are present,
    add the remaining numbers from setB pointer to the output array.
```

Note: This will work only on sorted sets.

Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: The sample sets are not sorted. It's wrong to assume that. Besides, the algorithm won't work. Consider these sets: A(10,11,12...20), B(1,2,3...10) with offset(10) & limit(10). Your algorithm will first exhaust set B, then exhaust a, then fail.

Comment: @Amit the OP is about 2 SortedSets. And in the algorithm i have not included all the edge cases like what happens if the Sets are smaller than the offset or limit (This is just an approach).

Comment: You're right that the OP mentions SortedSets, but look at the data, it's not sorted. Regarding the "edge cases" there aren't any, there are 20 different values between the 2 sets, you're supposed to skip the first 10, and return the next 10 (set B). Your algorithm will either crash or return 0 values. And edge cases matter greatly. Without them many algorithms could be improved by several factors.